# R markdown: Why R Studio can't locate my .bib file?

Tags: r, reference, markdown

I am trying to use reference in the R Markdown. When I try to export the markdown to Word or Html, I received the following error:

pandoc-citeproc: user error (Not found: bibli.bib)

So, it is clear that R Markdown can't find the bib file. The bibli.bib is at my R directory. I created a copy in many other folders to see If I find the right one but I didn't have success. Would you know where should I place  the .bib file so R Studio can find it?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you put a bibliography field in the metadata at the top of your document, like [the example here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html)?

Comment: Yes, I did. If I just run the code below, I have the same error. the .bib file is not found.
---
title: "Sample Document"
output: html_document
bibliography: bibli.bib
---

Comment: Wondering if this was resolved. I'm dealing with the same issue. Two separate .Rmd files in same directory, both pointing to the same .bib file. The syntax between the two identical. One compiles with the bibliography, the other throws the same error you noted. Very strange.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Make sure your bibliography file doesn't contain a hidden extension and thus have a name different than what you think it is. For example, if you created it using Notepad, a .txt extension is often added automatically, and may not even show up when you view the file in your folders. To check this, check the files properties. To change the extension, follow the instructions here:
http://www.thesitewizard.com/faqs/save-without-txt-extension-notepad.shtml